# Supernatural Episode inspiration for Once Upon a Time

Tags: supernatural, origin, once-upon-a-time

Is the episode [Bedtime Stories](http://www.tv.com/shows/supernatural/bedtime-stories-1138359/) from [Supernatural](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460681/?ref_=ttep_ep_tt) the inspiration for the plot structure of the series [Once Upon a Time](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1843230/?ref_=nv_sr_1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I don't think that it is. Although there is no documentation as to whether or not it "borrowed" any idea from that episode if you come to think about it then you will see that the storyline of Bedtime Stories is pretty common.

There are a lot of times similar plots in movies, series and literature about little girls creating their own fantasy worlds and living in them. It isn't a new and uncommon storyline so to start believing that "Once Upon a Time" inspired by that specific episode.

If you come to think about it it is easier to believe that Supernatural got inspired by stories like "Alice in Wonderland" and  "Pan's Labyrinth" (without of course believing that it actually did as I have said it is a pretty common storyline) rather that believing that inspired "Once Upon A Time".

But as there is no information about it everything is just an educated guess.

(Although if it actually had happened then I think that there would be some information about it.)

Comment: Thanks.  Supernatural definitely took information from other fairy tales and ghost stories - I believe that is even stated in several episodes, ie. mythology and nature gods.  The last bit is more to the point - there would be information out there citing the episode as inspiration.

Comment: You are welcome. Supernatural is inspired by mythology and folklore from all over the world. Greek, indian, asian etc. Also of course it is inspired by fairy tales and general stories. Sometimes it is solemnly based to them as some episodes are dedicated to a specific fairy tale. But in the last seasons most episodes are inspired by religion. An episode ""Hammer of the Gods" was inspired by almost every religion in the world (although some of the Gods there come from mythology).

Answer (score 0):

The episode "Bedtime Stories" was actually based on the original Grimm fairy tales before they were taken and made 'kid-friendly'.

Now, *Once Upon A Time* should have had the same inspiration for the series based on said fairy tales.